# Connect data between services | Microservice node.js

Tags: node.js, database

How to use data across databases?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Hb2l.png)

I don't understand how data can be shared between two databases. Should I use the tool? or what technique And does the data query have to be done using ORM?

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.